# Why did international wizards not come to help against Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

There's talk of wizards abroad and we see the students from Beauxbatons and Durmstrang, but if Voldemort really is trying to take over the world of magic, why was there never any sign of any wizard armies from abroad coming over to help?

Comment: Some international wizards (like Karkaroff) obviously joined the Dark Lord.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fear. Politics. Fear. Closer to Home. The Chosen One. Psychology.

No other country wanted to try and help through fear if Voldemort won then who would be next? The country that helped the people standing in his way.

You have to remember that the British Ministry of Magic fell. That would instill fear into the Ministry of Magic equivalents in other countries. Also the wizarding worlds don't really have armies, the Ministry has Aurors, up until The Battle Of Hogwarts only the Order of The Phoenix stood in Voldemort's way and only a few members were known openly. (It can be argued all good teachers were also members of the OOTP however not openly)

Yet more fear, Dumbledore was known to be the most powerful wizard of the time although I would say the general consensus was torn between him and Voldemort. When Dumbledore died I would imagine this would strike fear into the hearts of anyone who had ever met him.

The question about international wizards arises a lot but when you think about it how many English wizards actually helped out in the fight against Voldemort? Not many at all, people hid from him and from his pure blood regime but most did not fight. Only the Aurors and the Order fought.

England also had what the media had dubbed "The Chosen One" he would no doubt save the day. The hope of the free world was resting upon Harry's shoulders and if he couldn't do it who could?

Also the Bystander Effect: it is a lot easier to stand by and do nothing if everyone else around you is standing by and doing nothing. More keywords include Diffusion of Responsibility the more people are witnessing the less the responsibility you feel to actually do something. So for all the countries standing by they could all say well "no one else is helping out why should we". Interesting to read up on would recommend.

Comment: Voldermort and Dumbledore, the most powerful wizards in the whole world were both somehow Brit. For all we know that's what the Brits claimed. There could have easily been more powerful wizards and witches outside Britain.

Answer (score 8):

No doubt Voldemort wanted to *eventually* secure world domination, but he would not have been so stupid as to advertise this fact. If anyone asked, he would have said he was simply trying to become the wizardly ruler of Britain.

Wizards in other countries might have:

- Admired Voldemort's sheer power;
- Had sympathies for Dark Wizards, or even been Dark Wizards themselves;
- Been afraid of Voldemort, and hoped they could make a deal instead of fighting him;
- Been confident of their ability to deal with Voldemort if he ever threatened their interests;
- Had problems closer to home which occupied most of their attention and resources;
- Had some sort of grudge against the British Ministry of Magic and been quite happy to see it fall; or
- A combination of the above.

The other side of this coin is that the British MM would have been reluctant to allow interference in what it saw as internal British affairs. Like politicians anywhere, they are proud and protective of their independence. A team of international Aurors marching in to deal with Voldemort would not necessarily have been welcome.

For a historical parallel, consider the rise of the Nazi party in Germany. Some people outside Germany were concerned; but others were ambivalent or positively welcomed Hitler's seizure of power. Even those who opposed Hitler never seriously considered a military invasion of Germany to *prevent* him from becoming ruler in 1933. They only went to war in 1939, when they were no longer willing to tolerate Hitler's external aggression.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. It is unlikely that anti-muggleism was absent in other nations. In some countries, it might actually be prevalent public sentiment of wizards. So other ministries had to worry about their own communities or even appease the domestic loonies before going to UK. For more cautious ones, it simply wasn't their fight.

Answer (score 1):

**Voldemort never came out in the open.** The ministry did not officially fall, just had a change of leadership. Not even all the people in Britain knew about Voldemort's control of the ministry. The major events happening in Britain wrt the larger wizarding world were Dumbledore's death(Nobody is truly sure how, they just believe Harry's story or the Ministry's, but could be a random murder as long as no one knows the Voldemort connection)

**Harry's image was tainted with the possibility of his being involved in Dumbledore's death.** So it was hard for people from other countries to really take in that Voldemort was back, controlling the Ministry and that he had brought about Dumbledore's death. And the "Good" side was non-existent as long as Harry was under doubt.

**Voldemort's terror was localized to Britain**( similarly as Grindelwald never was powerful in Britain) He had not had enough time and power to export his terror before he "died", largely thanks to Dumbledore's efforts, one may guess.